# Differential geometry exercice from Kristopher Tapp's book

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I have problem with this exercice from Kristopher Tapp's book "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces"

**EXERCISE 1.42. (Page 32)** Let $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a unit-speed curve. Let $t_{0} \in I$ and assume $\kappa\left(t_{0}\right) \neq 0$. For sufficiently small $h>0$, prove that the three points $\gamma\left(t_{0}-h\right), \gamma\left(t_{0}\right)$ and $\gamma\left(t_{0}+h\right)$ are not collinear.

**My attempt:** I think the question means: prove that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $h >0$, if $h<\epsilon$ then the three points $\gamma\left(t_{0}-h\right), \gamma\left(t_{0}\right)$ and $\gamma\left(t_{0}+h\right)$ are not collinear.

I tried proof by contradiction. Assume that there exists a sequence $(h_{n})_{n\geq1}\subset \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$ such that  $h_{n} \rightarrow 0 $ , and $(\alpha_{n})_{n\geq1}\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \gamma\left(t_{0}+h_{n}\right)-\gamma\left(t_{0}\right)=\alpha_{n}\left( \gamma\left(t_{0}-h_{n}\right)-\gamma\left(t_{0}\right) \right)$

(It's easy to show that $\alpha_{n} \rightarrow-1 $ when $n \rightarrow \infty $),

using Taylor expansion we get

$\left\{\begin{array}{l} \left.\gamma\left(t_{0}+h_{n}\right)-\gamma\left(t_{0}\right)=h_{n}  \gamma^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)+\frac{h_{n}^{2}}{2} \gamma^{\prime \prime}\left(t_{0}\right)+o\left(h_{n}^2\right)\right)
 \\ \gamma\left(t_{0}-h_{n}\right)-\gamma\left(t_{0}\right)=-h_{n} \gamma^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)+\frac{h_{n}^{2}}{2} \gamma^{\prime \prime}\left(t_{0}\right)+o\left(h_{n}^2\right)\end{array}\right.$

from this and the above equation we get

$\left(1+\alpha_{n}\right) h_{n} \gamma^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)+\left(1-\alpha_{n}\right) \frac{h_{n}^{2}}{2} \gamma^{\prime\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=o\left(h_{n}^{2}\right).$

I can't find any contradiction and I can't find where I can use $\kappa\left(t_{0}\right) \neq 0$.

Comment: In the equation containing terms $\gamma ', \gamma'$ you probably need to use the $\kappa (t_0)$ not equals zero. However I don't know what were the assumptions already taken preceding the question regarding the smoothness of curves. I hope the result would hold even if the curve is not necessarily differentiable in neighborhood of $t_0$ and at $t_0$ its behaviour is given by the curvature. Intuitively it means at that point if the slope of curve exist and not equal to one then in some neighborhood it is not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it. You have already agreed that $\alpha_n\to -1$ as $n\to\infty$. So we're going to conclude that the only way your expression can be $o(h_n^2)$ is for $\gamma''(t_0)$ to be $0$. This is equivalent to saying $\kappa(t_0)=0$. (Recall that $\gamma'(t_0)$ and $\gamma''(t_0)$ are orthogonal!)

I think your argument is overly complicated. Rather than introducing the contradiction, the sequence, and the $\alpha_n$, just consider
$$\big(\gamma(t_0+h)-\gamma(t_0)\big)\times\big(\gamma(t_0-h)-\gamma(t_0)\big).$$
I would recommend writing $\gamma'(t_0)=T_0$, $\gamma''(t_0)=\kappa_0 N_0$. Now use your Taylor
expression and you'll get
$$(h T_0+\tfrac{h^2}2\kappa_0 N_0+o(h^2))\times ({-}h T_0+\tfrac{h^2}2\kappa_0 N_0+o(h^2)) =
h^3\kappa_0 B_0 + o(h^3).$$
Since $\kappa_0\ne 0$, the two vectors are indeed linearly independent for $h\ne 0$.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to conclude that easily? We don't know how fast $1+\alpha_n$ converges to $0$. If we use that the taylor expansion is equal to $o(h_n^3)$ however it seems to work. Still takes a bit of work.

Comment: @spinosarus123 I should have stated explicitly that since $\gamma$ is a unit-speed curve, the vectors $\gamma'(t_0)$ and $\gamma''(t_0)$ are orthogonal. So it does follow immediately.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer, thanks. I found a way to complete my solution, I proved that $\frac{1+\alpha_{n}}{h_{n}}$ converges, from this I proved that $\gamma'(t_{0})$ and $\gamma''(t_{0})$ are linearly dependent and since they are orthogonal we conclude that $\gamma''(t_{0})=0$ (a contradiction).

Comment: note - you're using the cross product in R^3. The given curve is in R^n.

Comment: @Alon I honestly missed that detail. Wedge (exterior) product will work fine for $n>3$, but I would agree that is beyond the scope of most undergraduate differential geometry courses.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worthwhile proving the more general statement:

Let $\vec{\gamma}:I\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ be a smooth curve, $0\in I$ and $\kappa_0\neq 0$. Then $\exists\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall a,b\in(0,\epsilon)$ the points $\vec{\gamma_{-a}},\vec{\gamma_0},\vec{\gamma_b}$ are not collinear.

Indeed, stated like this we can clearly assume WLOG that  $\gamma$ is unit speed.
Looking at the Taylor expansion
$$\vec{\gamma_s}=\vec{\gamma_0}+s \vec{T_0}+\frac{\kappa_0}{2}s^2\vec{N_0}+s^2\vec{R_s}\qquad \lim_{s\to 0}\vec{R_s}=\vec{0}$$
and writing $\delta_s:= \gamma_s-\gamma_0\ $ we have that: $$\quad \vec{T_0}\cdot \vec{\delta_s}=s + s^2(\vec{T_0}\cdot\vec{R_s})\quad\text{and}
\quad \vec{N_0}\cdot \vec{\delta_s}=\frac{\kappa_0}{2}s^2 + s^2(\vec{N_0}\cdot\vec{R_s})$$

It follows that $\ \exists \epsilon>0$ so that
$\forall s(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\ s\neq 0$
$$ \text{sign}(\vec{T_0}\cdot \vec{\delta_s}) = \text{sign}(s)\quad{and}\quad \vec{N_0}\cdot \vec{\delta_s}>0 $$
Now pick any nonzero $a,b\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of opposite signs. A proportion relation $\vec{\delta_a}=\lambda\vec{\delta_b}$ is impossible - multiplying both sides with $\vec{N_0}$ (resp. $\vec{T_0}$) you arrive at contradicting conclusions regarding $\text{sign}(\lambda)$.